# Spring Boot: Mapped one request to two different object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, request

I have a request body with data for two different object, for example.

```
{
    "First": "Stack",
    "Second": "Overflow"
}
```

`First` was for domain object `FirstPart`, `Second` was for domain object `SecondPart`, if we want to map one object we can do it like so.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAll(@RequestBody FirstPart first) {

}
```

Thus it automatically mapped into `FirstPart`. But, how we mapped two or more object, I'm thinking just add another `@RequestBody` surely not work right? By the way, I'm using `@Entity` in my domain object and Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the two entity objects in to one object and pass that wrapper object to your controller.

e.g.

```
class Wrapper{
    First first;
    Second second;
    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAll(@RequestBody Wrapper wrapper) {
      // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can just send to each domain object then.