# How to map a JSON Object Request to two different JAVA Objects in Spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have JSON Request object like below:

```
{
    "customer" :
    {
        "id" :  100,
        "firstName": "Customer First",
        "lastName": "Customer Last"
    },

    "student" :
    {
        "id" :  "ABC-100",
        "name": "Student Name",
        "age": 20
    }

}
```

Now, I have a spring boot rest controller to read this request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Instructor persistInstructorInformation(@RequestBody Object studentAndCustomer){
...

}
```

My Question is how we can retrieve this information in a way other than using Object class.

I am not trying to use a Wrapper class as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275881/9728637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requires an entity class：
TheEntity：

```
public class TheEntity {
    private Customer customer;
    private Student student;
    // getter and setter
}

public class Customer {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getter and setter
}

public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    // getter and setter
}
```

then use ThenEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Instructor persistInstructorInformation(@RequestBody TheEntity studentAndCustomer){
    System.out.println(studentAndCustomer)
    ...
}
```

To put it bluntly, it is to encapsulate objects according to your needs

Comment: I get your point. You are using a wrapper class. Let's say I use something else with the customer. Teacher and Customer json. I would have to write one more wrapper to address that. Can we find a unified way to resolve it?

Comment: @SubhenduDas emmm, in the actual development of applications, the functions are realized according to the requirements, and we cannot make unlimited compromises. For example, the product manager of the company stipulates that this function should store student information, so when we agree on the interface parameters with the front end, we will 
The way the parameters are passed has been negotiated.

Comment: @SubhenduDas Even if the processing you design is extremely general, there are always exceptions.